# What are the environment variables to set to run sawserver upgrade in OBIEE?

Tags: oracle11g, oracle10g, business-intelligence, catalog, obiee

I am trying to run the upgrade of a 10g catalog to 11g. I need to run it using the command sawserver -upgrade (executing it in $ORACLE_HOME/bifoundation/web/bin/).

When i run the command i see the error

```
./sawserver: error while loading shared libraries: libsawhttpserver643r.so: cannot open   shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I believe it is due to environment variables not being set. Can anyone help me with the required environment variables to make the command work.

PS: Though the upgrade can be done using the upgrade assistant i need to use this feature to run the upgrade.

Comment: @better_use_mkstemp any pointers ? I tried the google search in vain

Comment: @Victor HDC any pointers ?

Comment: Why don't you try going through ua.bat (which Upgrade Assistant uses) and see what all environment variables are being set. ua.bat can be found in <OBIEE_MW_HOME>/Oracle_BI1/bin/ua.bat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run bi-init.sh to set environment variable.

". $MW_HOME/instances/instance*/bifoundation/OracleBIApplication/coreapplication/setup/bi-init.sh"